# How to send notifications from a college server to students mobiles?

Tags: android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I am building an app for colleges and they want to have push notification function in their app but from their college server side they want to send notification. I have tried to send notification from FCM but i have build it from my fcm id. So how to transfer it to college server? Any idea?

Comment: plz help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Building the client-side app is only half of the solution. You have to work with the college to build an application server that will actually send the notifications to Google/Firebase.

Firebase notifications work like this:
**(A) Your App Server (college) -> (B) Google/Firebase -> (C) Your App (on user devices)** You only have B & C set up, but you need to create A.

The [Firebase Cloud Notification site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) has all the information about setting up a notification server, but you will probably need to work with the existing college IT staff / networking administrators.